# How to iterate a product rows to columns in C

Tags: c, matrix, do-while

I've the following problem: I've a matrix nxn ( a multiarray A[n][n]) and a vector b[i], with which I do a row to columns product between those two arrays and generate a new array c[i].

The first part of the code works correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (void){

    double A[4][4]={{0,0,1,0.5},{0.33,0,0,0},{0.33,0.5,0,0.5},{0.33,0.5,0,0}};
    double b[4]={0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25};
    double c[4]={0.,0.,0.,0.};
    int n,i,j;

    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        for(j=0;j<4;j++){

            c[i] += A[i][j]*b[j];
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        printf("c[%d]=%lf\n",i,c[i]);  

    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

In this way i will obtain a vector of 4 dimension like:

```
c[0]=0.375
c[1]=0.082
c[2]=0.332
c[3]=0.207
```

Now the problem is that I would like to iterate the program untill the difference between the componets of the vector b[i] and those of vector c[i] is at maximum of 0.001. To do the iteration I thought to make a do/while, but i don't know how to make the iteration. I will show what I thought to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (void){

    double A[4][4]={{0,0,1,0.5},{0.33,0,0,0},{0.33,0.5,0,0.5},{0.33,0.5,0,0}};
    double b[4]={0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25};
    double c[4]={0.,0.,0.,0.};
    int n,i,j;

    do{
        b[i]==c[i]; /* new add, but i don t know if it is the right place to put it..*/
        for(i=0;i<4;i++){
            for(j=0;j<4;j++){

                c[i] += A[i][j]*b[j];
            }    
        }   
    }while(abs(b[i]-c[i])<0.001); /*the condition into the while should be correct*/

    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        printf("c[%d]=%lf\n",i,c[i]);  

    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The results should be:

```
c[0]=0.38
c[1]=0.12
c[2]=0.29
c[3]=0.19
```

But it doesn't... how should I do?

Comment: Your while will end as soon as there are two elements that have the difference you want, and doesn't check on *all* the components. So when you'll have two corresponding values such that `(b[i]-c[i])<0.001)`, your while will exit. Hint: use a different variable instead of `i` in the while, and increment it manually inside the loop.

Comment: How can I do for checking all the components?

Comment: You should have a separate `if` check inside the `while` and only if the check is good, increment the variable which will proceed the `while` loop.

Comment: I don't understand where to put the 'if' inside the 'while'... the only way to put a control for each condition could be 'while((abs(b[0]-c[0]) < 0.001) && (abs(b[1]-c[1])< 0.001) && (abs(b[2]-c[2])< 0.001) && (abs(b[3]-c[3])< 0.001))'... but if I'll work with a bigger vector it wouldn't be so quick to do... may you write me what do you mean Maroun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second program, you set `b[i] = c[i]`, but `c` is initially zero. Presumably, you want to multiply `b` by `A` until the iterations converge. Also, you use the `abs` function, which takes an integer argument. You should use `fabs` instead for doubles.

What algorithm are you implementing here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
  double A[4][4]={{0,0,1,0.5},{(1.0/3.0),0,0,0},{(1.0/3.0),0.5,0,0.5},{(1.0/3.0),0.5,0,0}};
  double b[4]={0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25};
  double c[4]={0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0};
  int i, j, k;

  for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    for(j=0; j<4; j++)
      c[i] += A[i][j]*b[j];


  do
  {      
    k = 0;

    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
      b[i] = c[i], c[i] = 0;

    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
      for(j=0; j<4; j++)
        c[i] += A[i][j]*b[j];

      if(fabs(b[i] - c[i]) < 0.001)
        k++;
    }
  }while(k < 4);

  for(i=0; i<4; i++)
      printf("c[%d] = %lf\n",i,c[i]);  

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i m implementing the pagerank, and it should converge... [link]http://www.math.cornell.edu/~mec/Winter2009/RalucaRemus/Lecture3/lecture3.html.

Comment: i m trying to compute the first example

Comment: Ah, my bad, I wasn't setting the `c` vector back to zero each time. The code above now converges: I removed the print statements and added the `c[i] = 0` in the first `for` loop within the `do` loop.

Comment: Also, I changed the `0.33` to `(1.0/3.0)` to avoid numerical errors. If you leave it to two decimal places, it doesn't converge to the correct vector.

Answer (score 1):

```c
b[i]==c[i]; /* new add, but i don t know if it is the right place to put it..*/
```

Seems there is a typo. If you mean an assignment you should use `b[i]=c[i]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your program will end as soon as there is two components in `b` and `c` that have difference less than 0.001, but you want to do this for *all* the components and not only one pair.

You might want to do something like this:

```
int k=0;
do {
     for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
       b[i] = c[i];
       for(j=0;j<4;j++) {
         c[i] += A[i][j]*b[j];
       }
       if(abs(b[i]-c[i])<0.001)
        k++;    
     }

} while(k<4);
```

But be careful to not enter an infinite loop! You might want to perform other checks.

Comment: The `if(abs(b[i]-c[i])` shouldn t be inside the `for(i=0;i<4;i++)`?